# How to make a search less sensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a search form in my app but the search is too strict.

For example, when I search for "idea" the results won't include the word "ideas".

Here's my search:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("key_word like ? or title like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
end
```

How can I make the search less "strict"?

Comment: not clear with your question. Above query will give you result as if you search for `idea` it will give you search result including `ideas`

Comment: Yes you're right, I wanna say, if I search "manage" the results won't return  "managing", for exemple.

Comment: If you want your search to be that smart (managing would match term manage) you'd likely want to normalize keywords and indexed data, using some stemming library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
def self.search(query)
  where("key_word like ? or title like ?", "#{query}", "#{query}")
end
```

if querystring is 'idea', it will only search for 'idea' not for 'ideas'